# FOL help with generalized induction.

Tags: induction, first-order-logic

Mostly I am having problems with the base cases, I have done inductive proofs before but these feel odd; so either I'm doing the inductive proofs right and it just feels a bit different or I'm completely wrong.

Where $A$ is a formula, let $a(A)$ be the number of atomic formulas in $A$ and let $b(A)$ be the number of binary (two-place) truth-functional connectives in $A$.

Use induction on formulas to show that $a(A) = b(A) + 1$.

You can use the following template to structure your proof:

Base Case: Let $A$ be any atomic formula.

Inductive Case ($\lnot$): Let $A$ be $\lnot B$.

Suppose $a(B) = b(B) + 1$.

In the base case I am bit confused I think that we have $a(A)=1 $ and $b(A)=0$ so $a(A) = b(A)+1$

We then let A be $ \neg B $ and we want to show that $a(A) = b(A) +1$.

$a(A)= a(B)= b(B) +1$ by IH and $b(A)= b(B) $  shows us that $a(A) = b(B) +1 =b(A) +1$. which is the desired result?

Next we want to show the other operations.

Base Case: Let $A$ be any atomic formula.

$a(A) =1$ and $b(A)=0$ so $a(A) = b(A) +1$

Inductive Case ($\ast$): Let $A$ be $B \ast C$ where $\ast$ is one of $\land, \lor, \to$.

Suppose $a(B) = b(B) + 1$ and $a(C) = b(C) + 1$.

Let $A= B * C$  we want to show that $a(A) = b(A)+1 $

Now $a(A) = a(B) + a(C) = b(B) +1 + b(C) +1$ by IH twice.

We also have that $b(A) = b(B) + 1 + b(C)$ by def'n.

Now we can write $a(A) = b(B) +1 + b(C) +1$ as $a(A) =  (b(B) +1 + b(C)) +1= b(A) +1$ which is the desired result?

Comment: You are along the right lines. The base case is the case where $A$ is an atomic formula $X$ say. In which case, you are correct in saying that $a(X) = 1$ ($X$ contains just one atomic formula, namely itself) and $b(X) = 0$ ($X$ contains no binary connectives).

Comment: The induction steps look correct to me. The only small detail that is a bit odd is that you repeat the base case after you have done the negation case.